# Could you teach me? this meaning nginx-vod-module location ~ ^/p/\d+/(sp/\d+/)?serveFlavor/

Tags: nginx

Im studying nginx vod module but I dont understant this meaning "~ ^/p/\d+/(sp/\d+/)?serveFlavor/"
if you understand this meainging, teach me please

https://github.com/kaltura/nginx-vod-module

```
location ~ ^/p/\d+/(sp/\d+/)?serveFlavor/ {
        vod hls;
        
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers '*';
        add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers 'Server,range,Content-Length,Content-Range';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, HEAD, OPTIONS';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
        expires 100d;
    }
```